# Center align div content responsively

Tags: html, css

I need to center align div content responsively.

```css
.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpwi_inner {
    display: table;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 50%; 
}

.wpwi_row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_main">
    <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
    <div class="wpwi_outer">
        <div>Outer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_inner">
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Time</div>
            <div>8:02 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Pressure</div>
            <div>999 hPa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Visibility</div>
            <div>10000 Meter</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Cloudiness</div>
            <div>98%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunrise</div>
            <div>5:37 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunset</div>
            <div>6:39 PM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I center align content of wpwi_inner div so that content will remain center aligned if font size increase or decrease ?

Comment: It should work fine with just `margin: 0 auto;` in the two divs `wpwi_main` and `wpwi_inner`. If you want to change the font size for all of it, put font-size in `wpwi_main`

Comment: Thanks @Bman70.  I would like to keep two columns as close as possible without line break. I would like to keep like this image when font size is 28px   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYOzI.png and I would like to keep like this image when font size is 9px   https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Jc3.png

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at flexbox. You can tell flexbox children to be centered on either axis with very little effort and browser support is very strong these days.

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }

.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpwi_inner {
    display: table;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 50%; 
}

.wpwi_row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="wpwi_main">
      <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
      <div class="wpwi_outer">
          <div>Outer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="wpwi_inner">
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Time</div>
                <div>8:02 PM</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Date</div>
                <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Pressure</div>
                <div>999 hPa</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Visibility</div>
                <div>10000 Meter</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Cloudiness</div>
                <div>98%</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Sunrise</div>
                <div>5:37 AM</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wpwi_row">
                <div>Sunset</div>
                <div>6:39 PM</div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I enclosed your wpwi_inner within a div that has *display: flex*. Using the *justify-content* property we can make children of the flexbox stay centered on the main axis regardless of the size of the content inside.

Comment: Thanks @loomy. I would like to keep two columns as close as possible without line break. I would like to keep like this image when font size is 28px   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYOzI.png and I would like to keep like this image when font size is 9px   https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Jc3.png